# R igraph : undirected complete subgraph with k nodes- maximal node+edge weight

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I am beginning to think on a problem where I have a complete undirected graph where every node and edge have assigned non-negative weights (they could be zero though).  I want to select the set of k nodes (k is a given integer) that creates a subgraph with the maximal total weight (node weight + edge weight).  Is there a function within the R igraph package that would allow me to do this?  I know how I would make an integer program out of this in R using the Rsymphony package (I'm an operations research guy by training) but if I can use something pre-packaged even better.

Thanks in advance.